# Intervention Analysis with binary time series

Tags: time-series, binary-data, intervention-analysis

I need to do a intervention analysis to see if a marketing campaign affected conversion rate.

I would normally would use Causal Impact package to train a time series and then forecast it on the post period, then run a statistical analysis between the two. However, since conversion rate is bounded between 0-1, I don't think that will work.

I suspect can I use a logit with time fixed effects, but am not sure. I have around 3 years of data, so I can use dummy variables or something to pull out seasonality. I have weekly and yearly seasonality.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply use Logistic regression instead of time series? As you say, you can control for seasonality using dummy variables. Can you share more information, plots and simulated example. Your current question as it stands will not attract lot of answer due to lack of an example or reproducible example.

Comment: I'll try and get some examples. I think the data is confidential, but I can provide more. I think a major problem is it's population level, so I need to do a before\after analysis, for when a marketing campaign went into effect.